# Applied Chords notation

Tags: theory, piano, chords, notation, harmony

I have a chord in the key of F minor. The notes from the bass are
A natural , C , F , E flat. From textbook: " Identify the following applied chord . Symbolize the chord using functional and root / quality chord symbols.
A , C , F , Eb . Happy Fathers Day Summer Harmony.

Comment: V7/iv..........F7/A........If that's what your (or someone else's ) question means.

Comment: @Tim Thank you ! but 1st inversion => V65/iv  ...F7/A ... better ?

Comment: Never, ever had to use 65, 43, 42 in the last 65 yrs - can't see how it will change my music now! Academic!

Comment: The 65 , 43 , 43 notation (should be vertical: 6 over 5 ...) helps to clarify the position of the all important bass note identification. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Tim says in his comment ACEbF is F7/A. F7 is the dominant of Bb

So  V7/iv in F minor is the secondary dominant of Bb minor (iv) and  F7 with A in bass is the 1st inversion of FACEb.

Answer (score 0):

The identification of this applied chord { A , C , F , E flat } is best described as :  V65 / iv  and  F7 / A   .( unless Richard says otherwise )

Comment: @Richard : would you agree ?